# CPU fan sounds like jet engine

Tags: macos, hard-drive, cpu, fan, temperature

I have imac G5 24" intel 2.66 Ghz early 2009 model A1225 Running Mac OSX 10.9.2 version Mavericks The unit was damaged in a move. Replaced the LCD and Hard drive temp sensor, have to start in safe mode fan runs very fast I can access internet but bar at top flashing but loads. Could it be either the bios sensor, hard drive, or even temp sensor from hard drive.

The normal temp reading should be 50-95 f (10-35 c) the temp is reading 127 degrees celcius at this time. The above temp is what it should be reading according to apple.

Thank's any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with my iMac when I first got it. You need to reset SMC.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/17422856#17422856